# How to list daemon (services) process in linux, as with psutil?

Tags: python, linux, psutil

I am trying to print the current running services (daemon process?) in linux using psutil

In windows, using psutil I can get the currently running services with this code:

```
def log(self):
        win_sev = set()
        for sev in psutil.win_service_iter():
            if sev.status() == psutil.STATUS_RUNNING:
                win_sev.add(sev.display_name())
        return win_sev
```

I want to get the same effect in linux, I tried using the subprocess module and POPEN

```
 command = ["service", "--status-all"]  # the shell command
 p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)        
 result = p.communicate()[0]
 print result
```

However I would like to know if I can get the same result using psutil, I tried using the

```
psutil.pids()
```

But this only shows

```
python
init
bash
```

But when I run service --status-all I get a much bigger list including apache,sshd....

Thanks

Comment: Try this: ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?

Comment: @user574362, `ps` and `psutil` inspect the kernel's process table, but the kernel doesn't see systemd services as different from any other kind of process.

Comment: ...that said, if `psutil.pids()` is only showing you that minimal list, it makes me wonder if maybe you're running this code in a Docker container or other limited namespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't understand, does that mean that I can do it using psutil? also I think I got confused, what is the difference between systemd process and the normal process?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am currently testing it in WSL, does that change the output?

Comment: ...as for whether WSL changes your output, make sure you're comparing to `ps auxw` or similar *in the same environment* when checking whether your output from `psutil` is complete. By contrast, if `service` is a WSL-ism that lists Windows-native services, that's a very different beast.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am sorry hehe, i was talking about psutil.pids()

Comment: No, the "it" I was asking about is whether you're trying to list only services, or if you're just trying to list *all* PIDs, inclusive of but not limited to services.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ps auxw is showing the following init ro, -bash, python script, ps auxw

Comment: ...also, whether you're talking about Windows services, or systemd services, or something still different from that. (The typical way to list services on modern Linux distros is `systemctl`, not `service`)

Comment: Okay, so the WSL view of the process tree has only those four -- meaning the other things (like Apache) that aren't shown aren't WSL-native processes. This is all in accordance with what one would typically expect, and makes your question very Windows (and WSL)-specific.

Comment: ...which is to say, you're not really asking how to do something *on Linux*, you're asking how to do something *on WSL*, and should edit the question accordingly (or test on a *real* Linux system instead).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am sorry about the confusion, I mainly want to write a script that displays running services, I did easily on windows but I got confused when I tried to do it on linux because every other thread I saw suggested using actual commands, thanks for the help!!

Comment: ...and are you trying to make that script show *Windows* services from WSL, or show *Linux* services? If it's Linux services, the whole idea of a "service" depends on the init system your distro uses, so the question needs to be specific to a specific init system -- be it systemd, or runit, or upstart, or daemontools, or so forth.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Show linux services, WSL is just the environment I am using to test my code, its not specific to it

Comment: ...*most* modern Linux distros use systemd; if `systemctl` lists the same services you want, then those services are also represented as cgroups. See https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/490 for discussion of exposing cgroup metadata in psutil.

Comment: Gotcha. You'll need to test on a Linux distro that actually uses the same init system you're trying to develop for.

Comment: Once you've got a PID, you can read the cgroups it's in from `/proc/<PID>/cgroups`; if that PID is associated with a systemd service, the list of cgroups will contain things like `1:name=systemd:/system.slice/dbus.service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>The `service` command in WSL shows *Windows* services. As we've determined (in in-comment discussion) that you're trying to list *Linux* services, and using WSL only as a test platform, this answer is written to apply to the majority of Linux distributions, rather than to WSL.</sup>

---

The following will work on Linux distros using systemd as their init system (this applies to most modern distros -- including current releases of Arch, NixOS, Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, etc). It **will not** work on WSL -- at least, not the version you quoted, which does not appear to be using systemd as its init system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import psutil

def log_running_services():
    known_cgroups = set()
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        try:
            cgroups = open('/proc/%d/cgroup' % pid, 'r').read()
        except IOError:
            continue # may have exited since we read the listing, or may not have permissions
        systemd_name_match = re.search('^1:name=systemd:(/.+)$', cgroups, re.MULTILINE)
        if systemd_name_match is None:
            continue # not in a systemd-maintained cgroup
        systemd_name = systemd_name_match.group(1)
        if systemd_name in known_cgroups:
            continue # we already printed this one
        if not systemd_name.endswith('.service'):
            continue # this isn't actually a service
        known_cgroups.add(systemd_name)
        print(systemd_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_running_services()
```